# Enviar email con informacion de MySQL

Tags: mysql

Como dice la pregunta necesito enviar un email con información obtenida al ejecutar una sentencia (`Select * from` por ejemplo) pero no tengo ni idea de como hacer esto (mi nivel de MySQL no es muy avanzado), en MSSQL lo haria mediante un job y usando el cliente de correo que viene en MSSQL por defecto, mi pregunta es como haría algo como esto pero con MySQL? agradecería cualquier sugerencia o comentario ya que como lo mencioné no tengo ni idea.

PD. Se como creare el job (Evento en MySQL) y como haré la sentencia, lo que no se es como enviar el email automáticamente sin que el usuario mueva un solo dedo.

Comment: Creo que mysql no tiene soporte para enviar mails. Deberias usar algun tipo de lenguaje como PHP

Comment: Exacto mysql no envia email, tengo un codigo para enviar correo tambien con informacion de mysql (esto se hace al ejecutar una funcion haciendo click en un boton) pero lo que quiero es saber si existe una forma de que se envie automaticamente, sin tener una aplicacion (en php, c#, java, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Con una UDF<sup>1</sup> es posible ejecutar un programa externo en MySQL. Por ejemplo, puedes instalar<sup>2</sup> la librería [SYS](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys), la cual contiene la función [`sys_exec`](https://rawgit.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys/master/lib_mysqludf_sys.html#sys_exec).

Ésta función puede invocarse en un *trigger*<sup>3</sup> y se le pueden pasar los argumentos que se requieran para ejecutar el programa externo.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER INSERT
   ON table_name FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   -- variable declarations
   DECLARE exec_str VARCHAR(500);
   DECLARE ret_val INT;

   -- trigger code
   SET exec_str = CONCAT("sh /tmp/load.sh ", NEW.user_mail);
   SET ret_val = sys_exec(exec_str);
   IF ret_val = 0 THEN
      -- OK
   ELSE
      -- ERROR
   END IF;

END;
```

---

*Notas*

1. Véase [§26.4 Adding New Functions to MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-functions.html) del [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/). Hay una lista de UDFs en [`http://www.mysqludf.org/`](http://www.mysqludf.org/).
2. Algunas librerías ofrecen un script de instalación. Más detalles en [§26.4.2.5 UDF Compiling and Installing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/udf-compiling.html) del [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/). [Aquí] puede encontrar un camino.
3. Véase un tutorial en [Create Trigger in MySQL](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx). También [Example, create and use triggers in MySQL - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKDqZCkBRZ8).

Answer (score 0):

Después de leer tu último comentario, lo que te sugiero es que trabajes con el `cron.php`.

Este fichero, es una "tarea programada", que pones el código ´PHP´, el cual dices que ya tienes listo. Luego a nivel de servidor, es cuestión de configurar la hora que quieres que se envíe.

Como consejo, primero create la página y testeala, para ver que te lo hace y luego, creas el cron.